# Numpy Array missing dates when I get data from an api (yfinance)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, yfinance

I am trying to gather stock data on an Numpy Array in which the dates of the stock prices are in the first column. When I turn the data directly into an array I will get `[ 30.99  32.08  32.12 ... 318.66 315.77 323.5 ]` here is my code below.

```
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf

def price(ticker):
    company = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    price = company.history(period="10y")
    array = np.array(price)
    return array
aapl = price("AAPL")
Aaple = aapl[:, 0]
```

If I use a dataframe I will get this

```
def price(ticker):
    company = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    price = company.history(period="10y")
    df = pd.DataFrame(price)
    df.drop(df.columns[i], axis=1)
    return df
aapl = price("AAPL")
print(aapl)


                  Open    High     Low   Close     Volume  Dividends  Stock Splits
Date                                                                          
2010-05-27   30.99   31.40   30.81   31.33  166570600       0.00           0.0
2010-05-28   32.08   32.08   31.33   31.77  203903700       0.00           0.0
...            ...     ...     ...     ...        ...        ...           ...

2020-05-22  315.77  319.23  315.35  318.89   20450800       0.00           0.0
2020-05-26  323.50  324.20  316.50  316.73   30880340       0.00           0.0
```

I can reset the dataframes index `df.reset_index()` and be able to access the dates. How come I cannot access dates in the array, what is the fix? I do not want to use dataframes since arrays are much faster.

Comment: Good Question indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, these are weekends and holidays, the markets is closed on those dates. Conversion to numpy array is problematic as dates are either `datetime` or `string` while the rest of the data is `float`. To keep the first column you need to convert it into `float` or `int` with, for example, a Julian day function https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.to_julian_date.html

Comment: yes, but yfinance will only show days in which the market is open

Comment: When you try to convert the data into numpy array dates are discarded as they have a different data type (`datetime` or `string`) from the rest of the data `float`. If you really want to keep first column you need to convert it to `float` or `int` (see for example Julian day https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.to_julian_date.html)